# Calculate new height based on tilt angle and horizontal distance

Tags: geometry

Let's start with a vertical wall that is 12 feet high. Attached to the top of this wall is a roof that has a 10 degree downward pitch angle. As we move horizontally away from the original wall, how high is the roof at 10 feet, 20 feet and 30 feet? I'm looking for a formula where I can enter the starting height, roof pitch angle and distance which will then calculate the new height based on horizontal distance from the starting height. - Thanks -

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the slope $m$ of the roof, such that the height $y$ is given at a distance $x$ from the wall by the equation

$$ y = m x + b $$

where $b$ is the wall height.

Given the angle $\phi$, the slope is calculated with $$ m = \tan \phi$$

So the roof height $y$  at distance $x$  is given by

$$ y = (\tan 10°) x  + 12 $$